# Is it safe to install two different VirtualBox Guest Additions at the same time?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I was wondering if it is safe to install both Windows and Linux versions of VirtualBox Guest Additions? I searched around in google but couldn't find an answer.

I need to make a vbox image that works both on Windows and Linux hosts (for shared folders and such). But I don't know if installing a second guest additions after the first one will cause any unforeseeable conflict/problems.

-- EDIT --

Part of the confusion I had was that under Linux/Ubuntu, it was possible to install VBox Guest Additions via the `apt-get` system. This led me to think that there are Windows vs Linux versions of Guest Additions.

I've tested to install the Guest Additions on Windows host from the official Oracle source, and then used the virtual image under Linux. Features like shared folders etc. work just fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guest additions are host OS agnostic. It's probably the same.

Comment: @heavyd Thanks. So did you mean that, if I make an image under windows & install guest partitions there, and then import that image to linux and install guest partitions again, I would be reinstalling the same thing?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about that. You may be right. Do you have any reference for that?  The installation of guest partitions seem quite different to me. Under Ubuntu, I usually had to do `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guestxxx` to make it work. Under windows, installing it from the menu works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISO file containing the GuestAdditions (which is mounted in the GUEST to install them) contains several versions (32/64 bit, Windows, Linux and some Unix variants) for different GUEST OSses. That may be confusing.

The Guest-additions are always installed on the GUEST OS. Not on the HOST.
The HOST side is integrated into the VirtualBox installation itself and not changeable.

The only important thing to keep in mind that you should use the same version of Guest-additions in the GUEST as the VirtualBox version on the HOST.
Even though a version difference may appear to work just fine, there is a possibility of subtle errors occurring, system instability or performance loss if the versions don't match.

So if you move a virtual machine between hosts, make sure to update the GuestAdditions if needed.
Newer versions can be installed over the old one.
If the GUEST has a newer version than the HOST you best upgrade VirtualBox itself on the HOST. (The GuestAdditions can be downgraded in the GUEST, but that can be very complicated, especially on a Unix/Linux GUESTs.)

Answer (score 0):

The guest additions are specific to the guest, it doesn't matter what host you install them from. You can transfer a VM from one host to another. As seen in the answer to [What's the recommended way to move a VirtualBox VM to another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer). (Sorry, Oracle's VB help server is down so I can't give you references to that at present).

The additions provide OS specific drivers and tools to enable the guest OS to communicate with VirtualBox not directly with the host.