# VirtualBox not exporting disk image in OVA

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, export, vdi, vmdk

I have a VM I am attempting to export. When I attempt to export it (OVF 2.0), the OVA file is a mere ~12kb and does not contain the disk image. The only potentially relevant difference I see compared to other VMs which export successfully is that this has a `.vmdk` on a SCSI controller rather than a `.vdi` on a SATA controller.

I am aware of the ["copy the entire folder" method](https://superuser.com/a/633449), but this is less than ideal for my application.

I am running VirtualBox 5.0.30 on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to unzip it and check that there is no disk image? If your original VM contains disk image, Virtual Box should easily export configuration file and disk image into OVA file.

Comment: @Stuka Yup. The ovf file doesn't list an image in `<DiskSection>` but does list a UUID under the storage controllers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see any other option except, trying to convert VM with any 3rd party converter, if you still have the original VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VMDK was using an SCSI controller. Once I moved it to the SATA controller, exporting the VM included the disk image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below things. I checked on Virtualbox on Ubuntu host.

1. Shutdown the vm
2. Detach disk
3. Convert disk to .vdi using "VBoxManage clonehd"
4. Attach new disk to SATA storage on your vm
5. Power on and verify everything is working
6. Shutdown vm and try to export again