# Upgrading home PC, how to move VirtualBox VMs in a data drive to the new PC

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, data-transfer

I am upgrading my home PC. On my current PC, all my VirtualBox VMs reside on a data drive separate from the primary OS drive. The current PC uses Windows 10 and the new PC will also be using Windows 10.

I have about 30 VirtualBox VMs on that data drive. My question is if I can do the transition using the method listed below.

- Move data drive to the new PC
- Assign the data drive with the same drive name (e.g. `D:`)
- Install the same version of VirtualBox I have right now onto the new computer
- Move my `.VirtualBox` directory from `C:\Users\foo\.VirtualBox` to my new PC

Comment: [Check this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer)

Comment: All you have to do is transfer the VMs and their configuration file.  Which directories those files are in are documented in the Vbox manual

Comment: I agreed, it is indeed duplicate after I read the referenced thread carefully.  The solution is exactly what I described in my original question.  Those steps worked, I tried it during my transition of my new PC.

Answer (score 0):

Install the VM;s data drive in new pc. [ or even copy the VM folders to a new drive, keeping the old as a back up]
Then install Virtualbox as normal on the new pc.then under "preferences" select "Default Machine Folder" and point to the new drive where the VM;s are.
then select "Machine Add" Ctrl+A.  select the VM;s one at a time. To import.
Have done it many times