# __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ error after exporting to MacOS

Tags: macos, virtualbox, migration, macos-catalina

**TL;DR:** How to fix `__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__` error when starting Ubuntu VM, which was migrated from Windows 10 host to macOS host?

---

I was warking inside a guest OS Ubuntu on a host OS Windows 10, and everything was working okay.

Recently however I had to switch to macOS; so I've exported my VM following the first scenario from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer) (though the second seems to be recommended, it didn't work for me, unfortunately, — the VM just didn't appear in the list). Now, when I try to start my VM on a MacBook, a couple of seconds after I choose to boot "Ubuntu", the VM "crashes unexpectedly" with the following logs ([excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqZiK.png)):

```
Thread 4 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff6******* _abort_with_payload + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff6******* abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff6******* abort_with_payload + 9
3   com.apple.TCC                     0x00007fff6******* __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 163
4   com.apple.TCC                     0x00007fff6******* __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.114 + 500
5   com.apple.TCC                     0x00007fff6******* _tccd_send_message_block_invoke + 231
6   libxpc.dylib                      0x00007fff6******* _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
7   libxpc.dylib                      0x00007fff6******* _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 69
8   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff6******* _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff6******* _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 369
10  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff6******* _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 1316
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff6******* _pthread_wqthread + 362
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff6******* start_wqthread + 15
```

I'm not an expert in Apple, Mac, VirtualBox, or Ubuntu (I wish I was!). Can anybody help me identify the problem and fix it?

Comment: Hey Dima! I am hitting this same issue. Looks like you *can* get around it by running virtualbox as root. I'm following these threads to learn more, though

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=99299
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=97141

Comment: Before you try sudo (which will work!) disabling audio on the virtual machine, then rebooting. I think that could solve the problem

Comment: @zlipp Thanks, I'll try that and let you know

Comment: @zlipp Unfortunately, that didn't work. I ran `sudo -b virtualbox` (after which I had to import and configure the VM again). Now I just don't get any crash reports, VB just stops working and closes VM window

Answer (score 6):

The exact same error was fixed by disabling Audio in the settings of the VM for me.

Comment: Thanks for this.
Looking at the row containing "CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__" leads me to believe there is something wrong with VirtualBox permission settings. And disabling audio actually fixed this. So, I guess at some point (because this just started happening to me), something changed in that area. I'm running VirtualBox 6.1.14 r140239 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Cheers!